# Supervised learning with random-ish game data

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

**Goal**

I am fairly new to machine learning and after some online education, this is my first real project. It is a game called Ouril in which you and your opponent each have six "houses" with four starting stones in it. You alternately play a house and distribute its stones, which might lead you to capture the opponents stones. You win by capturing 25 stones.

The goal of this project is to have a trained function that predicts how good a move is, given the current game state, so that the bot can pick the best predicted move and play it.

**Setup**

I built some non-ai bots (random-bot, max-bot, min-max-bot) and made them play many games against each other. The game logs each played move into a json file. I use the logged moves to train a Keras model with a Tensorflow backend. The model consists of some Dense Layers with sigmoid activation functions, since I want the predicted value to be between -1 and 1.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_shape=(15,), init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(12, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

**Training Data**

Each move in the game is logged like this: `[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0]` the first 12 fields are the number  of stones in each house, then the house that is being played in this move, then my and the opponents current score and last is the score for this move.

At first I defined the score of a move simply as the amount of captured stones this move. I trained the model on this data and got to an accuracy of about 0.7. I am sure this could be improved upon, but with this kind of data the models top predictions would just be as good as the max-bot i already have.

So I made the score be dependent on the players next moves. If the player takes 4 houses in a move, his previous three scores increase by 2, 1 and 0.5 while the opponents last scores decrease the same way.

**Problem**

With this new training data I only get an accuracy of maybe 0.1.

I think this is because the new data is way more homogeneous (scores are closer to 0) and also because in this data there might be many different scores for the same move.

Since this is a very broad kind of question, here are some concrete ones:

- Is there a better way to represent the score in my data?
- Do I need other layers in my model? Other parameters to them?
- Is mean_squared_error a fitting loss function for this problem?
- Is Keras the wrong tool for this problem (maybe linear regression instead?)

Thanks

---

source here: https://github.com/sra448/ouril-game/blob/master/learning/learn.py

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to predict. You say you want an output in [-1,1] but later it sounds like you are trying to predict the number of stones captured.

Comment: You are right, in my first attempt I really wanted to predict the number of captured stones and therefore maybe sigmoid was not usefull. But the ultimate goal is to predict the "how much closer to winning do I get" of a move and there I guess [-1,1] would be a nice range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The goal of this project is to have a trained function that predicts
>   how good a move is, given the current game state, so that the bot can
>   pick the best predicted move and play it.

One way to do this is to take every moved played in your games database as an input example, and use the outcome of the game (+1 or -1) as the label for each example.

The advantage of this approach is that you do not have to try and engineer features about the move such as how many stones it captures - which may or may not be relevant.

The disadvantage is that each individual move is a weak predictor of the final game outcome, since it may or may not have been relevant. To balance this you need a lot of training data.

Another weakness is that your bots might never play certain types of moves, so they won't be present in your training set. To avoid this problem you might want to add some randomness to moves played by your bots. This was the method used in the latest iterations of AlphaGo.

Of course you can combine both approaches and use the final game outcome as your training labels, but also include features such as how many stones are captured. This way the model can decide for itself exactly how important these features are.

> Is there a better way to represent the score in my data?

There is one big problem with your current representation: You are encoding the location of the move as the number of the house. Your neural network will not know how to interpret this correctly. You should use a one-hot encoding instead.

Also you mention each move distributes stones, but I don't see how you have encoded the distribution of stones.

I would consider the following encoding:

```
[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4] # houses
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] # move origin
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0] # move destinations / #of stones at each
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0] # capture locations / sizes
```

Please forgive me if the particular encoding doesn't represent a legal move - I don't fully understand the rules. Hopefully you should get the idea.

You can use these four arrays as channels in a single input to a 1D convolutional neural network. I believe a CNN will perform much better here, because it is better at capturing local structure.

> Is mean_squared_error a fitting loss function for this problem?

Yes.

One final note: The accuracy you get isn't a great indicator of how good your value function is. What's more important is how it scores potential moves relative to each other. The true test is how well your bot performs when you plug in your value network to evaluate moves.

**EDIT:** One more final, final note: Consider building an [MCTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_tree_search) bot. You can build it from only the rules of the game (little or no knowledge of strategy required) and it should be much stronger than what you have and should give you much better training data for your value network project.

Comment: Thank you for your fast and clear advice. I can see how I don't even need to try to score each move myself, since this is kind of the job of the network. One-hot was also just the right keyword to get me on track, together with your suggestions of encoding the move destinations and capture locations as well. I will try your suggestions and report back :)

Comment: You're welcome! This sounds like a big project, so good luck!

Comment: PS: Also consider using Monte Carlo Tree Search. An MCTS bot will likely be much stronger and should give you better training data for your value network project.

Comment: So I one-hot encoded the playing-house and extended the data as you suggested having the score only be -1 or 1 depending on win/loss. Running this data with my dense network yields about 0.5 accuracy (which is still a measure of how well the network "fits" the data, right?). Next I try to use a CNN instead. Also MCTS looks very promising (and complicated :D)

Comment: Yes, accuracy is a measure of how well you're fitting. Since there are only two outcomes, which I assume have similar frequencies 0.5 accuracy means you aren't doing better than random guessing, unfortunately.

Comment: I hope the CNN will help - but I think using it I will lose the current score as a parameter since it doesn't fit in spatially. Also, maybe way more data will help. Would you use MCTS just to generate training data? From what I grasp so far, it seems that MCTS can also be the AI itself.

Comment: If your engines are playing weak, nearly-random moves then the game outcome won't be predictable. You can encode current score as a constant channel for CNN's. And yes, MCTS by itself might make a strong bot!

Comment: Thanks again Imran! I have a running MCTS bot, but I still struggle with the CNN. You helped a lot.